A finite subgroup of $P\subseteq GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ has the determinant of the sum of its matrices in the integers
Let M be the sum of all matrices of this finite subgroup, prove that $det(M) \in\mathbb{Z}$
I know that I must use the fact that M is invariant under multiplication by elements of P, which can be easily seen since that P is a finite subgroup.
My attempt
By using Cauchy Binet formula and the invariance of left and right multiplication by elements of P I was able to find out that the determinant of any matrix in P has to be
equal 1 . I was able to find that $det (\mathrm A +  \mathrm B) = \det (\mathrm A) +  \det (\mathrm B) + \mbox{tr} \left( \mbox{adj}(\mathrm A) \mathrm B \right)$ . Now as determinant of A and determinant of B are both equal to one, it remains to prove that $trace(\mbox{adj}(\mathrm A) \mathrm B)$ is an integer. Am I in the right track? How to proceed?
